# Responsive CSS Check

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, web

Trying to get content to appear in this css to respond well on the website, but the content makes a scrolling bar on the left to right which is hard to manage on mobile. The only part that responds well is the custom nav for mobile, the #wrapper, content, and footer all don't respond too well.

```
/**********************************
GENERAL
***********************************/
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}


img{
  max-width: 100%;
  /*width: 250px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding:1px;
  border:1px solid #021a40;*/
  }

#wrapper{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-style: dashed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 960px;
  flex: 1;
background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

li{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
}
/**********************************
HEADING
***********************************/



/**********************************
NAVIGATION
***********************************/
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/**********************************
FOOTER
***********************************/

.footer{
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #ccc;
}



/**********************************
PAGE: HOME
***********************************/

#ownerimg{
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding:1px;
  border:1px solid #021a40;
}


/**********************************
PAGE: ADOPTION
***********************************/
.adoptionimages{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding:1px;
  border:1px solid #021a40;

}

.adoptionimages2{
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding:1px;
  border:1px solid #021a40;
}

/**********************************
PAGE: CONTACT
***********************************/
label {
    clear: left;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 22px 32px 6px 0;
    text-align: right;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #F2F2F2;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 94px;
}

form li {
    list-style-type:none;}

form {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 silver;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 60px auto;
    padding: 60px 30px;
    width: 430px;
}



input {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , gold 0%, white 20%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 51px 5px 90px 5px;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 4px 0 21px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #334F71;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 256px;}

textarea {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , gold 0%, white 20%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 51px 5px 90px 5px;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 0 0 21px;
    padding: 12px 20px 0;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #334F71;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 256px;

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;
        border-radius:30px;
}


textarea:-moz-placeholder {
        color: #a1b2c3; text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #38506b;
}


input[type=submit] {
    width: 185px; height: 52px; float: right; padding: 10px 15px; margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #999;
    border: 1px solid #556f8c;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #718DA9 0%, #415D79 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#718DA9), color-stop(100%,#415D79));
}



/**********************************
COLORS
***********************************/
```

Comment: provide some fiddle please.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xnbnz3zd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of having a `scrollbar` in your page is bcoz of the text overlapping to your wrapper. Also don't declare fixed width if you want to make your page responsive. Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/xnbnz3zd/2/

```
#wrapper p{
  word-break:break-word;
}

#wrapper{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-style: dashed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  height: 1000px;
  flex: 1;
background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is getting rid of the fixed height enough to fix the border so that the text doesn't overlap that as well?

Also do I apply the same css to the images so they don't overlap the border as well?

Comment: @hirollin please marked it as answer and also upvote.

Comment: @hirollin on your image. just make `width:100%` so that image will follow the width of your wrapper.

Comment: Upvoted, but it wont show since I'm new and low. Hope you'll upvote me as well :)

Thanks for your help!